# Trouble with Comparing

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare my User Form input to a column of numbers in excel; find the number that my User Form input is less than or equal to and assign a variable the value of the cell next to the cell it was compared to (i.e. if Input is less than or equal to A2 then variable is set equal to B20) When I do this, it gives me the last value in the B column whether or not the Input value is less than the A column.

I have tried an Exit For after the If Then but this just stops it after the first iteration.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim TextBox5 As Integer
If UserForm1.OptionButtonRes.Value = True Then
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To 216 Step 1
            If Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value >= TextBox5 Then
            ValueCharge = Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Value
            End If
        Next i
End If
MsgBox (ValueCharge)
```

Comment: You may have to convert the textbox to a numerical value as by default it's text. In any case `valuecharge` will only ever show the last value as you are overwriting.

Comment: You could try adding `Exit For` after assigning the value to `ValueCharge`

Answer (score 1):

TextBox5 is only text that looks a number. You need to convert to a true numerical value for a valid comparison.

```
    For i = 1 To 216 Step 1
        If Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value >= val(TextBox5) Then
            ValueCharge = Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Macro functioning as desired. Thank you.